# Ignore Safari's Initial Page Load popstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm using pushState and generating the page view on popstate events based on the history.state of the current page.

If there is no history.state I (hope) to reload the document.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if( window.history.state !== null ){
        // page was ajax created and history created by pushState
        // recreate with ajax
    }
    else{
        // page was loaded from server normally
        document.location.reload()
    }
}
```

At issue is Safari fires a popstate event on the initial page load.
Chrome and Firefox fire popstate on the back/forward browser button.

I want to ignore the initial load popstate event on Safari (ideally without setTimeout and without browser detection).

Additionally, the site is a mix of links - some that will trigger pushState and some that will load normally from the server - so if a user is ten pages into navigation history and clicking the back button, the history will have a mix of pushState pages and non-pushState pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popstate on page's load in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421769/popstate-on-pages-load-in-chrome)

Comment: [Question about the same bug in Chrome, which was also webkit-based, has lots of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421769/popstate-on-pages-load-in-chrome). BTW, I don't see this behavior in recent Safari 11.1.2.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem saving the initial order value obtained from `window.history.state.order` in a variable. When the on popstate event is triggered, the value previously stored is compared to the current order value. It they are the same then nothing is needed to be done (you have to ignore the initial popstate value triggered by Safari). Here you can see and example:

```
var initial_oder = window.history.state.order || 0;    
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if( window.history.state !== null && window.history.state.order !== initial_order){
        // page was ajax created and history created by pushState
        // recreate with ajax
    }
    else{
        // page was loaded from server normally
        document.location.reload()
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Hey IllRepublica, I appreciate your answer, I think it's got me super close. I'm just not sure where you are pulling `window.history.state.order` from? is that from `history.pushState`?

Comment: IllRepublica is defining it on their own app.