# Using pushState, visiting another site, then hitting back gets me just my XHR content

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

Apologies for the somewhat vague title, hopefully these steps to reproduce will show you the problem I've got:

1. In Google Chrome, visit [griffinalters.com](http://www.griffinalters.com) (the problem doesn't seem to exist in recent versions of Firefox or IE);
2. Click on any card;
3. Visit another site (about:blank works well for this);
4. Hit back, and you should see just the HTML loaded for the partial request (which happens to look like http://www.griffinalters.com/card/29/?ajax).

The link that I pushState'ed with was `/card/29/`, but the link I loaded into my div was `/card/29/?ajax` (per the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309477/moving-back-to-a-pushstate-entry-that-used-ajax)). Originally I was trying to check for the presence of `XMLHTTPRequest` in `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` (for what it's worth, I'm using Django's [`is_ajax`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) method).

I load the chunk of HTML returned by my XHR with:

```
function update_main_card_from_url(theurl) {
    $(".primary-card").load(theurl + '?ajax');
}
```

which in turn is called by:

```
function micro_card_click(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var theurl = $(this).attr("href");
    SimpleHistory.pushState(theurl);

    update_main_card_from_url(theurl);
}
```

What I'd really like to understand is why hitting back from a different site doesn't load the URL I pushed, but loads the URL that was fetched. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I noticed it as well. It looks like it is a Chrome 'feature'. I personnally like it: the user comes back to *what he left*

Comment: Just curious, what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: You might try to try setting `cache: false` for the ajax load.  You can do it either with `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})` or by using the lower level `$.ajax` call instead of `$.load` and passing it as an option.  Your pushState code is probably not the culprit here.  Chrome is always a little funky with xhr and the back button.